# How to cancel a http.post() while it is waiting for a response?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular6, rxjs5

This is some code from an angular component. It is a search component where `characterIndexes` is an array of search results.

The search results are retrieved by typing in a searchbox which triggers the `searchtrigger` or `searchEmptyTrigger` depending on its content. After getting the first results I have to perform another `http.post()` to get the names belonging to the indexes so I can sort them ( I omitted that part from the code ). Then the results are inserted in the `characterIndex`-array.

A similar thing happens when `searchEmptyTrigger` is triggered. Except for the `characterIndex`-array is just set to empty and no http-requests are needed.

The issue I run into is that in some cases, when the `searchEmptyTrigger` is triggered, the code from the `searchtrigger` is still running ( due to delays because of the http-requests ).

The result is that the `characterIndexes` are empty first. And then it would fill up again after receiving the result from the http-request in the `searchtrigger`.

So the big question is: **'How to cancel my running `http.post()` while it is waiting for a response?'**

```
  public characters: any[];
  public characterIndexes: number[];

  let searchBox = document.getElementById('search-box');
  let searchTrigger = fromEvent(searchBox, 'input')
  .pipe(
    map((event: any) => event.target.value ),
    filter( text => text.length > 2 ),
    debounceTime( 500 ),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    switchMap( text =>  ajax(`https://esi.evetech.net/v2/search/?categories=character&datasource=tranquility&language=en-us&search=^${text}&strict=false`)
    )
  );

  let searchEmptyTrigger = fromEvent(searchBox, 'input')
  .pipe(
    map((event: any) => event.target.value ),
    filter( text => text.length <= 2 )
  );

  searchTrigger.subscribe( response => {
    if( response.response.character ){
      let characterIndexes = response.response.character;
        this.http.post('https://esi.evetech.net/latest/universe/names/?datasource=tranquility', characterIndexes)
        .subscribe( (charactersInfo: any[]) => {
           // do some stuff with this.characterIndexes and this.characters = [];
        });
      } else {
        this.characterIndexes = [];
        this.characters = [];
      }
    });

    searchEmptyTrigger.subscribe( () => {
      // reset values 
      this.characterIndexes = [];
      this.characters = [];
    });
```

PS: I am also open for an alternate approach that performs the same operations as the code above, where I can cancel the http-request.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use a `takeUntil(searchEmptyTrigger)`.

```
this.http.post('https://esi.evetech.net/latest/universe/names/?datasource=tranquility', characterIndexes)
        .pipe(takeUntil(searchEmptyTrigger)) // make sure to cancel the post if `searchEmptyTrigger` emits
        .subscribe( (charactersInfo: any[]) => {
           // do some stuff with this.characterIndexes and this.characters = [];
        });
```

---

PS, you could totally simplify your whole code into much less code.

Stay away from having `subscription` inside another `subscription`, like your `post` request.

You can merge them by using operators.
I'm lazy to write it all, :d

Comment: Thanks for the feedback on the embedded subscriptions. I am pretty sure it is part of the cause of the issue. I will read up a bit on the operators and hopefully figure out a better approach from there ;).

Answer (score 0):

Try this way ...

**Example :** The concept is to `unsubscribe` the observable object...

```
const request = this.searchService.search(this.searchField.value)
  .subscribe(
    result => { this.result = result.artists.items; },
    err => { this.errorMessage = err.message; },
    () => { console.log('Completed'); }
  );

  request.unsubscribe();  // <-- Hear you can cancel the API request.. 
  //Just set in when you need to cancel. It will works fine. 
  // E.x use with timeout or delay option of observable. 
}
```

Comment: I had the same intuition. But with the 2 sequential requests I cannot make sure if the second ( post-request ) is running. There might be a scenario where the `ajax( ... )` in the `switchMap()` is still running. The `.unsubscribe()` is then triggered on an `undefined` value. Then the second request will still take place when the first is finished.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. I will try to explain what went wrong first, after that I ll go over my solution.

**The problem**

In the question's code there was a problem. Before a new value was emitted, I would have already performed a http-request in the `searchTrigger`, but not in the `searchTriggerEmpty`. Therefore `searchTrigger` could be emitted after `searchTriggerEmpty` even tough `searchTrigger` had been initiated first.

**The solution**

The solution was to fix the emitting order. To do that the event would have to be emitted before any requests are made. And when a new event is being triggered the previous event should be cancelled ( `switchMap`-behavior ).

**Code explained**

- The `searchTrigger` emits events when someone types in the
  `searchBox`.
- Some pipes are added. `debounceTime( 500 )` and `distinctUntilChanged()` prevent the event from triggering too often.
- The `map` pipe returns the value types in the searchBox.
- The `switchMap` has a conditional statement inside it. This is where the best way to proceed is chosen.
- If the string is longer than 2 characters it will return an observable of an array of characterIndexes (it gets these by doing some http-requests and processing them).
- If the string is shorter than 2 characters it will directly return an empty array.
- The reason for using a `switchMap` here is that a currently pending process will be cancelled when a new value is being emitted.
- By subscribing to `searchTrigger` we can now process the latest search results.
- I also provided the function I used for `process_searchString()` so you have a better idea what it does / returns.

**Code**

```
let searchBox = document.getElementById('search-box');
let searchTrigger = fromEvent(searchBox, 'input')
.pipe(
  debounceTime( 500 ),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  map((event: any) => event.target.value ),
  switchMap( searchString => {
    if( searchString.length > 2 ){
      return this.process_searchString( searchString );
    } else if ( searchString.length <= 2 ) {
      return of( [] );
    }
  }),
);

searchTrigger.subscribe( ( characterIndexes: number[] ) => {
  this.characterIndexes = characterIndexes;
  this.characters = [];
  if( characterIndexes.length > 0 ){
    this.load_10characters();
  }
});
```

Disclaimer: At the moment of writing this I just learned to use rxjs. So if you see anything that should be improved drop in a comment.

PS: For those interested this video explains the switchMap better than I can ( and is entertaining too ): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rUZ9CjcaCEw

Extra `process_searchString()`:

```
  private process_searchString( searchString: string ): Observable<number[]>{
    return new BehaviorSubject( searchString )
    .pipe(
      concatMap( ( text: string ) => this.request_characterSearch( text ) ),
      concatMap( ( response: any ) => {
        if( response.character ){
          return this.request_characterNames( response.character )
        } else {
          return of([]);
        }
      }),
      map( (charactersInfo: any[]) => this.sort_alphabetically( charactersInfo ) ),
      map( (charactersInfo: any[]) => charactersInfo.map( characterinfo => characterinfo.id ) ),
    );
  }
```